# Rails route not working - not sure why

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

Having a routing issue, should be really simple but seems straightforward and just not working:

```
match '/api/get-locations-by-distance/:latitude/:longitude' => 'api#get_locations_by_distance'
```

with this call:

```
http://localhost:3000/api/get-locations-by-distance/34.035645/-118.233434
```

thx for any ideas

**edit #1**
If I update it to the following:

```
match '/api/get-locations-by-distance/:latitude/:longitude/:stub' => 'api#get_locations_by_distance'
```

and

```
http://localhost:3000/api/get-locations-by-distance/34.035645/-118.233434/stub
```

It still doesn't work.

**edit #2**
I tried adding the :format => false but this doens't seem to help either.

match '/api/get-locations-by-distance/:latitude/:longitude' => 'api#get_locations_by_distance', :format => false

with

```
http://localhost:3000/api/get-locations-by-distance/34.035645/-118.233434
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It thinks that `.233434` is format

Comment: hmm...shoot, what could be workaround? maybe adding some unecessary piece at end like `.233434/fill`?

Comment: You can try to use constraints, like `match '...', :longitude => /[+-]?\d+\.\d+/`

Comment: thx, did this in conjuction with constraints in @Tilo answer.

Comment: also for removing .json in the request, I set `:defaults => { :format => 'json' }` in routes.rb

Answer (score 0):

It's like Mik_Die said - the . is the delimiter for the format in Rails.

Here is a work-around: you can specify your own segmentation constraint.

```
match '/api/get-locations-by-distance/:latitude/:longitude' => 'api#get_locations_by_distance' , 
       :constraints => { :latitude => /\d+\.\d+/ , :longitude  => /\d+\.\d+/ }
```

See also:

http://x3ro.de/rails-3-routing-parameters-dots/